# How can I get my bars to be touching the x axis in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

After inputting this line of code using ggbreak `scale_y_break(c(6, 500))` my bars on my bar chart are now no longer touching the x axis. What line of code can I use to get them to not float?

I already have this line of code `scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log', breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 500, 1000), expand = c(0, 0))` which doesn't seem to keep my bars on the x axis. Yet when I just do `scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` my bars return to the x axis. However, I still want my y axis to be a log scale so have to combine to `scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log', breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 500, 1000), expand = c(0, 0))` yet when do this my bars are floating! Any help greatly appreciated!

```
## sample data
structure(list(...1 = c("Cell Line ID", "9-3", "21252", "21253", 
"21256", "21024", "21039", "21077", "A9156", "A9161"), ...2 = c("Genotype", 
"WT", "3KO", "3KO", "3KO", "3KO.7TG", "3KO.7TG", "3KO.7TG", "3KO.7TG.RI", 
"3KO.7TG.RI"), `C3b MFI x 10^3` = c("Human Serum", "825", "3.9140000000000001", 
"5.61", "4.9619999999999997", "0.85", "1.4259999999999999", "0.68100000000000005", 
"0.84", "0.86299999999999999"), ...4 = c("Serum+EDTA", "0.23599999999999999", 
"0.224", "0.20300000000000001", "0.20100000000000001", "0.247", 
"0.252", "0.22600000000000001", "0.246", "0.34200000000000003"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
myData %>% 
  #am now selecting the columns and rows need to use for my bar chart 
  select(c(2:4))%>%
  slice(2:10)%>%
  rename (genotype=...2) %>%
  mutate(across(c(2:3), as.numeric))%>%
  mutate(genotype = factor(genotype, levels = c("WT", "3KO", "3KO.7TG", "HC"))) %>%
  mutate(`C3b MFI x 10^3` = ifelse(genotype == "HC", 0, `C3b MFI x 10^3`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=genotype, y=`C3b MFI x 10^3`, color=genotype, fill=genotype, width=0.4)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "bar", lwd=1, position = position_identity())+ 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      x = "3KO",
      ymin = 3.914,  
      ymax = 5.61), 
      width = 0.2,
    color = "#e0a477",
    position = position_identity()
    )+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), size = 1.5) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("3KO.7TG" = NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log', breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 500,1000), expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#fcca92","#d0e5f6","#dcdcdc"), 0.3))+theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black")
  )+
  labs(x = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("WT", "3KO", "3KO.7TG±RI", "HC"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +  # Remove legend for the color aesthetic
  scale_color_manual(values = c("WT" = "black", "3KO" = "#e88840", "3KO.7TG" = "#425887"))+
scale_y_break(c(6, 500))
```

Comment: Hi, can you post your full ggplot2 code and if possible a sample of the data you are using by posting the dput() output?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`ggbreak` vignette where they show an example of a broken axis with a log-transformation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html#feature-5-compatible-with-scale-transform-functions)? If you need more help than that, then sharing 5 or 10 rows of sample data so we can test would be very helpful.

Comment: @PhDavey have posted full ggplot2 code have got so far and hopefully should be able to access sample data, not really sure how to do the dput() output thing though

Comment: @GregorThomas have had a look at that link thank you! Still can't seem to get the bars to touch x axis though - have linked excel sheet getting data from if that helps?

Comment: `dput` is the easiest and friendliest way to share sample data. `dput(myData[1:10, ])` makes copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of `myData`. If you put that code that results from `dput()` in the question, anyone can copy/paste it and have a sample of your data.

Comment: @GregorThomas okay have done dput command and seemed to work - hopefully that helps!